# What The Scythe meant by saying "Your People"? and "trials and inquisitions"?

Tags: helix

In the Helix series finale, there is a scene that The Scythe says:

> Seems Porto Rico was unnecessary after all.

And Dr. Alan Farragut says:

> You murdered hundreds of people.

And The Scythe answers:

> As your people have done for centuries with witch trials and inquisitions.

What The Scythe meant by saying "Your People"? and "trials and inquisitions"?

Could we say is it possible that Silver Eyed People are Vampires or Witches or mutants or even humanoid aliens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that silver eyes are an indication of genetic mutation/alteration which makes one immortal. "Our People".  Hence, non-immortals would logically seem to be to what Scythe is referring as"Your People".

[From the Helix Q&A Website](http://www.syfy.com/helix/photos/helix_questions?id=3)

**To your question on Witches and Trials and Inquisitions:**
As an immortal in the past it would have been easy to have non-immortals become suspicious and eventually jealous of those they believed might be consorting with demons to extend their lives.  I.e. witches and wizards.  Remember, contact lenses weren't exactly common in Salem, Massachusetts in the 1600s. :-)  Hence, we could easily see "trials and inquisitions" for those believed to be immortal and providing a basis for the myth of witchcraft.

**To your question on Vampires:** 
Long life (or immortality) is a defining characteristic of vampires along with the ability to rapidly heal from wounds other than decapitation.

[Hatake ability to heal](http://www.syfy.com/helix/photos/helix_questions?id=7)

This provides another reason for non-immortals to fear and persecute silver-eyed immortals. Too, vampires are known for "glamouring" victims. I.e. using a form of super-hypnosis. We see elements of such control in the way that Kyra Zagorsky's character Julia seems to be able to control/command those individuals infected with the Narvik virus.  Too, Narvik may have had a basis in an earlier Immortal disease. We know that the DNA used to create Narvik was derived from Dr. Hvit's head which Hataka was able to weaponize into Narvik. If so, it may have been that in a previous natural outbreak of a "proto-viral Narvik disease"--or something similar--a silver-eyed immortal was able to control those infected. Hence, leading to the myth about "glamouring" victims.

[Dr. Hvit DNA source for Narvik](http://www.syfy.com/helix/photos/helix_questions?id=16)

We also see in Puerto Rico the "Black Blood" disease name used. Vampires are intimately associated with blood in countless ways. A silver-eyed immortal who seems to be immune to an earlier outbreak and possibly controlling/influencing those infected could be perceived as "living off the blood" of his/her victims as the basis for a "vampire" myth.

**To your question on humanoid aliens:** 
As a completely non-canon answer. Many science fiction shows routinely gloss over the improbability of human/alien inter-fertility. Given that at least one of Julia's parents would have to be an alien (Hatake) and her mother seemed to be human, as a "medical" science fiction drama, I am hoping that particular trope is avoided.  I can't say it won't turn out to be that.  But, I am hoping for more. :-)